# Running Maven assembly:single with multiple profiles in one run

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-profiles

I have a project that I need to build the main code as well as the configuration files in separate tar files for different environments. The main code will be the same and it is packaged in single tar file.
The configuration though is different for different environment. I need to generate both main code and configuration tar files for all environment in one go.

The way I do is that the main code is packaged in one `<execution>` and the configuration files are packaged in another `<execution>` with build profiles as the difference.

The problem is that when I run `mvn -PdevA,devB,devC,devD clean deploy`, it will only execute with one of the profile I specified (it could be random).

Is there anything that I'm missing here?

Comment: Probably your profiles override each other. Show us the POM.